# What do you say to a waitress when you don't want any change?

Tags: idiomatic-language

What do you say when you give $50 to a waitress and you want to tell her the money includes the tip and you don't want any change? I could say "I don't want any change", but it's not straight to the point and a bit confusing and unidiomatic. It's something a non-native English speaker might say, but what do native speakers say?

Let's say you are billed for $30 and you give $50, which means you are giving more than 15%, but you don't want change since you are giving $20 in tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that "Keep the change" is the normal, idiomatic expression for this. The phrase is even defined in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_the_change) as:

> an instruction to a taxi driver, waiter etc. to keep the change from the amount handed over as a tip

That said, I'd like to add that there are other ways a native speaker might convey the same sentiment. Sometimes I will give the waiter my money, and simply say, "I'm all set."

Other times I might say, "I don't need any change. Thank you."

Most waiters have been in the profession for some time and they've become pretty adept at reading signals from customers.

Comment: I'm all set sounds better.

Comment: Never, ever, heard or used 'I'm all set'.

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic expression is "Keep the change."

> That will be $30 please.
>
> Here's $50. Keep the change.
>
> Thank you very much sir.

Comment: "Thank you very much sir." - or madam.

Comment: @MichaelH - Or, "Thank you very much. Have a nice evening."